# как добавить несколько картинок после текст вью

Tags: java, android

У меня есть проект приложения с возможностью добавлять текстовый ресурс в категорию избранное но я хочу добавить к нему изображения. К примеру: нажимаем в меню автомобили, у меня через стринг аррай, итем идет перечень описания  а мне нужно добавить  после текста  несколько картинок. Как мне это реализовать? (я новичек)

код item_loyout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/ic_item_background">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/textview"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imBut"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/favorite_im"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvText"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_favorite_button_on"
    tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />


<com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.SubsamplingScaleImageView
    android:id="@+id/imView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvText"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />
    <!--android:src="@drawable/superkar"-->
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>"""
```

пример кода MainActivity

```
        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavItemSelectedListener{
        private RecOnClickListener recOnClickListener;
        private DataAdapter adapter;
        private List<ListItem> listData;
        private RecyclerView rcView;
        private String category = "";
        private SharedPreferences pref;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);





    setupMenu();
    setRecOnClickListener();
    init();

    }
    private void setupMenu() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    MenuListFragment mMenuFragment = (MenuListFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.id_container_menu);
    if (mMenuFragment == null) {
        mMenuFragment = new MenuListFragment();
        mMenuFragment.setNavItemSelectedListener(this);
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.id_container_menu, mMenuFragment).commit();
    }
}

@SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
@Override
public void onNavItemSelectedListener(MenuItem item) {
    Toast.makeText(this, item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.id_favorite:
            updateFav();

            break;
        case R.id.id_car1:
            updateMainList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.car1), "car1");
            break;
        case R.id.id_car2:
            updateMainList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.car2), "car2");
            break;
        


    }
}
private void updateMainList(String[] array, String cat)
{
    category = cat;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder;
    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String tempCat = pref.getString(cat,"none");
    if(tempCat != null){
        if(tempCat.equals("none"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            {
                stringBuilder.append ("0");
            }
            Log.d("MyLog",  cat + "" + stringBuilder.toString());
            saveString(stringBuilder.toString());
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    List<ListItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i <array.length; i++)
    {
        ListItem item = new ListItem();
        item.setText(array[i]);
        item.setCat(cat);
        item.setPosition(i);
        list.add(item);
    }
    adapter.updateList(list,false);
}
// ИЗБРАННОЕ
private void updateFav()
{
    List<ListItem> listFav = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String[]> listData = new ArrayList<>();
    listData.add(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.car1));
    listData.add(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.car2));
    
    String[] cat_array = {"car1","car2"};
    for(int i = 0; i < listData.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int p = 0; p <listData.get(i).length; p++)
        {
            String d = pref.getString(cat_array[i],"000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
            if (d != null)if (d.charAt(p) == '1')
            {
                ListItem item = new ListItem();
                item.setText(listData.get(i)[p]);
                item.setPosition(p);
                item.setCat(cat_array[i]);
                listFav.add(item);
            }

        }
    }
    adapter.updateList(listFav, true);

}
private void init()
{
    pref = getSharedPreferences("CAT",MODE_PRIVATE);
    rcView = findViewById(R.id.rcView);
    rcView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    listData = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] car1Array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.car1);
    adapter = new DataAdapter(this,recOnClickListener,listData);
    updateMainList(car1Array,"car1");
    rcView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
private void setRecOnClickListener()
{
    recOnClickListener = new RecOnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(int pos)
        {
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Position = "+ pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String tempCat = pref.getString(category,"none");
            if (tempCat != null)
            {
                if (tempCat.charAt(pos) == '0')
                {
                    saveString(replaceCharAtPosition(pos,'1',tempCat));
                }
                else
                {
                    saveString(replaceCharAtPosition(pos,'0',tempCat));
                }
            }


        }
    };
}
private String replaceCharAtPosition(int position, char ch, String st)
{
    char[] charArray = st.toCharArray();
    charArray[position] = ch;
    return new String(charArray);
}
private void saveString(String stToSave)
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString(category,stToSave);
    editor.apply();
    Log.d("MyLog","saved data fav : " + pref.getString(category, "none"));
}
```

}        '''

DataAdapter

```
    public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.DataHolder> {
private Context context;
private RecOnClickListener recOnClickListener;
private List<ListItem> listItemArray;
private SharedPreferences pref;
private boolean isFav;
//private SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView;

public DataAdapter(Context context, RecOnClickListener recOnClickListener, List<ListItem> listItemArray) {
    this.context = context;
    this.recOnClickListener = recOnClickListener;
    this.listItemArray = listItemArray;
    pref = context.getSharedPreferences("CAT", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public DataHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout,parent,false);
    return new DataHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DataHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setData(listItemArray.get(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItemArray.size();
}

public class  DataHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    private boolean isFavChecked = false;
    private TextView tvText;
    private ImageButton imButFav;


    public DataHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvText);
        imButFav = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imBut);
        imButFav.setOnClickListener(this);
        //imageView = imageView.findViewById(R.id.id_contract);
    }
    public void setData(ListItem item)
    {
        tvText.setText(item.getText());
        if(!isFav){
            setFav(item,getAdapterPosition());
        }
        else
        {
            setFavOll();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        isFavChecked = !isFavChecked;
        if (isFavChecked)
        {
            imButFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_button_on);
        }
        else
        {
            imButFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_button_off);
        }
        if(!isFav){
            recOnClickListener.onItemClicked(getAdapterPosition());
        }
        else
        {
            deleteItem();
        }


    }
    private String replaceCharAtPosition(int position, char ch, String st)
    {
        char[] charArray = st.toCharArray();
        charArray[position] = ch;
        return new String(charArray);
    }
    private void saveString(String stToSave)
    {
        ListItem item = listItemArray.get(getAdapterPosition());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString(item.getCat(),stToSave);
        editor.apply();
    }
    private void deleteItem()
    {
        ListItem item = listItemArray.get(getAdapterPosition());
        String dataToChange = pref.getString(item.getCat(),"none");
        if (dataToChange == null)return;
        String replacedData = replaceCharAtPosition(item.getPosition(),'0', dataToChange);
        saveString(replacedData);
        listItemArray.remove(getAdapterPosition());
        notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
        notifyItemRangeChanged(getAdapterPosition(), listItemArray.size());
    }
    private void setFavOll()
    {
        imButFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_button_on);
    }
    private void setFav(ListItem item, int position)
    {
        String fav_data = pref.getString(item.getCat(),"none");
        if(fav_data != null)
        {
            char[] charArray = fav_data.toCharArray();
            switch (charArray[position])
            {
                case '0':
                    imButFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_button_off);
                    isFavChecked = false;
                    break;
                case '1':
                    imButFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_button_on);
                    isFavChecked = true;
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
public void updateList(List<ListItem> listArray,boolean isFav)
{
    this.isFav = isFav;
    listItemArray.clear();
    listItemArray.addAll(listArray);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет об одной картинке с какой либо стороны, можно делать в xml
`android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_drawable"`

Скорее всего вы не знаете количество картинок, которые нужно будет показать. В xml сделайте горизонтальный контейнер LinearLayout. Програмно добавляйте в него ваши картинки методом `addView`. Не забудьте указать LayoutParams для этих картинок. Возможно нужно будет `inflate` ваш контейнер.

Comment: Я не совсем понятно выразился в описании, у меня к примеру идет меню собака, кошка, хомяк. При нажатии на пункт кошка, появляется текст - порода, регион где обитает и так далее( я использую constraintlayout с кастомным бекграунд в который помещен TextView и ImageButton- для кнопки избранное)(  заполняю через стринг аррай) мне же нужно чтоб после( порода, регион ,где обитает)следом за ним ишли картинки( для них использую библиотеку com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.SubsamplingScaleImageView. Сложность заключается в том как это правильно реализовать в джава классе.